# Angular JS - How do I use a variable in an ng-repeat filter?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter an ng-repeat using a variable.

```
ng-repeat="data in datas | filter:{type:@{{someType}}}"
```

I am using blade template which explains the @.  When I hard code the type value I want to filter it works.  Not with the variable though.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit (I though you wanted someType to be rendered by blade):

You don't need to interpolate your argument in a filter. Simply do the following :

```
 ng-repeat="data in datas | filter:{type:someType}"
```

Comment: Right.  Perhaps I needed to be clearer.  someType is a variable from another data element (not the one being used for the ng-repeat).  So I need to use the @ so blade will ignore.  But as you point out - not required within the argument.  Thanks!!